# Render default value of views exposed filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a view in Drupal 7 using an exposed filter. When I access the view without any ($_GET) values in the URL I want to display all items. The drop down selection has the value -Any- as I want it, but the view is still empty, even the empty result text will not shown. If I hit the submit-button all items appear. 
Already tried different things from post I found about this, but nothing worked so far. I have no Idea why it is rendering nothing at all by default and why I can't make it render something...

Here are my settings for the filter:

- Exposed: YES
- Type: SINGLE
- FILTER Operator: IS ONE OF
- Options: -nothing_selected- (already tried selecting everything)
- Checked options: Reduce duplicates

I'm using View 7.x-3.5 and have CCK 7.x-2.x-dev enabled.
Hope anyone has an idea. Thanks a lot!

Saduras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may cause by the *Exposed form style* setting: Change it to *Basic* if it is *Input required*.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!